# How to integrate different modules in PHP Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, integration

I and some of my friends are trying to create a web based ERP system. I and five other guys are responsible for the Sales and Inventory management module and some other guys are doing the financial accounting module. The financial accounting is depended on the sales and inventory module.

The application is like this-: there would be three different levels of users who can log in to the system.

1. One will add/delete/update the sales information in the app
2. One will add/delete/update the inventory information in the app
3. The last one will deal with the financial accounting where he will add/delete/update info and sometime generate reports

We are using Codeigniter Framework. Now the problem is as we are doing the task from different locations I am very confused about how to integrate the modules(Financial Accounting+ Sales+ Inventory) when we are done with it.

Would you please kindly give me some suggestions on what steps should we take while developing it so that we can integrate those modules easily when are done.

Thanks in Advance :)

P.S If I have missed any information to provide, please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

The database design, and membership roles and permissions should be defined before you split your ways with the other team.

Once these are established you shouldn't have too difficult of a time developing your models and controllers that are specific to your sales and inventory management (while they are working on the ones that are specific to them). The same is true with your views, however I would structure both in a way that can easily be placed into a content area so that you can have someone later throw up some navigation / footer / header unless you already have a navigation schema setup and some design done.

Basically, there should be no issue with working in different teams if you're both working on the same database schema.

Comment: +1. :) Thank you very much for your reply. Your answer was very helpful. But one of my friends was suggesting to use API for each module. Do you think this is a good idea and easy to implement? Thanks again :)